# BABEL_ENV issue when running npm test in React App

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I have the following script in the scripts block of my package.json, this requires babel via babel-register- and sets the NODE_ENV to development in order to do so.

```
"test": "set NODE_ENV=development&&mocha --watch --require babel-register --require jsdom-global/register --require ignore-styles --require src/tests/helpers.js src/tests/**/*.js"
```

I am however getting this error:

```
Error: Using `babel-preset-react-app` requires that you specify `NODE_ENV` or `BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", "test", and "production". Instead, received:undefined.
```

I have tried many combinations of uninstalling, reinstalling, altering the order of requirements within my script and several other steps mentioned in [the main git issue for this error](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2377).

Can anyone see any glaring error in my method here? Full package below:

```
"dependencies": {
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
  "react": "^16.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
  "tslib": "^1.9.3",
  "typescript": "^3.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
  "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
  "watch-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
  "start-js": "react-scripts start",
  "build-ts": "set NODE_ENV=development tsc || exit 0",
  "watch-ts": "tsc --watch",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "start": "npm-run-all -p build-* watch-* start-js",
  "test": "set NODE_ENV=development&&mocha --watch --require babel-register --require jsdom-global/register --require ignore-styles --require src/tests/helpers.js src/tests/**/*.js",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "react-app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
  "chai": "^4.1.2",
  "enzyme": "^3.4.1",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.2.0",
  "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
  "jsdom": "^11.12.0",
  "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
  "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
  "sinon": "^6.1.5"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently using [`set`](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html) to specify your `NODE_ENV` variable which results in it not being available to child processes, i.e. the next command chained after the `&&` operator, which is `mocha`.

If you use [`export`](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) instead, you'll ensure it's available to child processes.

Change the beginning of your `test` script to the following:

```json
"test": "export NODE_ENV=development && mocha --watch ..."
```

---

**Cross-patform:**

`export` will only work in Bash environments. For a cross-platform solution  consider utilizing [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to set the environment variables instead. Example:

```json
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development mocha --watch ..."
```

Note: `export` has been replaced with `cross-env` and the `&&` operator is not necessary.

Comment: this worked perfectly, was not aware that child processes did not inherit the same env settings with `set`. Currently working in a bash environment so will stick with `export` for the foreseeable future! Cheers.